# converting a list of integer numbers to list of ranges

Tags: python-3.x

each of my inputs is a set of integer numbers which can be split into several continuous ranges and i want to convert each set into a series of ranges.
i found a code on the net as below:

```
from itertools import count, groupby
L=set(range(1,2000))
G=(list(x) for _,x in groupby(L, lambda x,c=count(): next(c)-x))
result= (",".join("-".join(map(str,(g[0],g[-1])[:len(g)])) for g in G))
print(result)

L=set(range(1539876,1540871))  #to be replaces by a set of integer numbers in real code
G=(list(x) for _,x in groupby(L, lambda x,c=count(): next(c)-x))
result= (",".join("-".join(map(str,(g[0],g[-1])[:len(g)])) for g in G))
print(result)
```

with the following results:

```
1-1999
1540096-1540870,1539876-1540095
```

as you can see for the second set of numbers it splits a single continuous range into two ranges,in my real datasets it acts even worse. i dont know whats wrong with this code that for some set of numbers it cannot function well.
 i appreciate if anyone could give me a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` is for collecting *contiguous* groups in a sequence.  Since you're passing it a `set`, which is unordered, you're getting into trouble as the terms aren't sorted.  If we add `L = sorted(L)`, we get:

```
>>> from itertools import count, groupby
>>> L=set(range(1539876,1540871))
>>> L=sorted(L)
>>> G=(list(x) for _,x in groupby(L, lambda x,c=count(): next(c)-x))
>>> result= (",".join("-".join(map(str,(g[0],g[-1])[:len(g)])) for g in G))
>>> print(result)
1539876-1540870
```